# MySQL php query flaws

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am to do a presentation on SQL Injection, and what better way to do it than to make my own php queries and show them to the class.
The problem is I have my DB and php code running flawlessly, but can't seem to find an exploit on my UPDATE query in an edit form I made.
If anyone could take a look at it and tell me how I could insert say a 'DROP TABLE' command or something of the sort, it would be extremely helpful!

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
$fname = $_SESSION["fname"];
$lname = $_SESSION["lname"];
$gender = $_SESSION["gender"];
$email = $_SESSION["email"];

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
    $fname = trim($_POST["fname"]);
    $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);
    $gender = trim($_POST["gender"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);

    $query = "UPDATE user_details SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', gender = '$gender', email = '$email' WHERE userid = '$userid' ";

    if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {


        echo 'Update complete!';

    }
    echo mysqli_error($link);
    // else { 

    //     echo '<p>' . 'Woah something went really wrong dude' . '</p>' ;
    //     echo mysqli_error($link);
    // }


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Edit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class= "form-inline" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["fname"]; ?>">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["lname"]; ?>">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["gender"]; ?>">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>">
    </div> 
    <div class = "wrapper">
            <label>UserID</label>
            <input type="text" name="userid" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"]; ?>">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <form action="action.php"><button type="submit">Back</button></form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried to piggy back a query by inputting as $userid 1234' ; DROP TABLE table_test --    but that didn't seem to work, currently looking more into how I could properly do it, but I'm sure that my noob code will be easy to crack for most people on this site

Comment: "I have tried to piggy back a query by inputting as $userid 1234' ; DROP TABLE table_test -- but that didn't seem to work" mysql_query doesn't support multiple SQL statements.

Comment: "The problem is I have my DB and php code running flawlessly, but can't seem to find an exploit on my UPDATE query in an edit form I made" only way you can exploit this is by using a timebased SQL injection vector.. `UPDATE user_details SET fname = (SELECT SLEEP(5)) --` for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most of the cases mysqli prevents multiple queries and MySQL itself has certain in-built security measures to prevent accidental deletion of tables and databases. So your `DROP TABLE` won't work.

But you can demonstrate a successful login attempt using MySQL injections.

Create a login form and pass data to the validation page. There write your query as,

```
query =  "SELECT * FROM `user`
     WHERE `username` = '." username ".' AND `password` = '." password ".'";
```

Now, in the login form enter username as `' OR '1'='1` and password as `' OR '1'='1`. so at the end the complete query would look like this,

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`='' OR '1'='1' AND `password`='' OR '1'='1';
```

this will return all the user records in the `user` table, and simply the application would login by using the very first record.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You saw right through me, I already have a working registration and log in example made which showcase what you just typed, but I wanted to show a DROP TABLE example on the edit form as the last example and leave the class shocked a show my DB changed (table dropped) by injecting the query in the edit.php form.
I'll just change the function call to mySQL instead of mySQLi since it's so secure

Comment: Yep try that too. but as i've said MySQL itself has some security built in. You may not have guaranteed results of `DROP TABLE`. But this login attempt is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you fully, but I will try to tell you why this seems to be a bad idea...

if I post to userid

```
$userid="';DROP TABLE XY;SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE fname = '"
```

your code would do...

```
$query = "UPDATE user_details SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', gender 
= '$gender', email = '$email' WHERE userid = '$userid' ";
```

which results in the query:

```
$query = "UPDATE user_details SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', gender   
= '$gender', email = '$email' WHERE userid = '';DROP TABLE XY;SELECT * FROM 
USER_DETAILS WHERE fname = '' ";
```

The queries would be

```
UPDATE user_details SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', gender   
= '$gender', email = '$email' WHERE userid = ''

DROP TABLE XY

SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE fname = ''
```

Each one of them is valid...now create a table XY and run the original query of your example with this posted injection...

I am missing something?

Edit: as @RaymondNijland pointed out the mysql function used in the example seems to block this kind of an attack. I am still considering it to be a dangerous code style, where only a driver creates security. Maybe there are future updates allowing batch sql, I would sleep better knowing my code doesn't open this kind of a door...

Comment: No that's perfect my man Peter thanks I will try it.
Edit: The idea is to find vulnerabilities and EXPLOIT them, since this is supposed to be an example to the class of how not to do things and the consequences of having a vulnerable system

Comment: mysql_query doesn't support multiple SQL statements so it will not work..

Comment: Raymond, do we still agree this is a bad idea?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see, so should I use a different function for the query? Again the idea is for the system to be vulnerable to SQL Injection to be shown as an example to the class

Comment: @john, if it helps you please mark the answer "correct"

Comment: @John only way you can exploit your UPDATE query is by using a timebased SQL injection vector.. `UPDATE user_details SET fname = (SELECT SLEEP(5)) --` as simple example the multiple SQL statements won't work.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Alright so what could I do to make it vulnerable to a DROP TABLE injection? Use mySQL_query instead of mysqli?

Comment: I was updating the answer to cover the topic opened by @RaymondNijland...

Comment: @John mysql_query or mysqli_query arn't vulnerable to multiple SQL statements injections and it's not possible  too make them vulnerable.. If the programmer was using mysqli_multi_query this injection will work just fine .